# Choosing a encryption key from Diffie-Hellman output

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish, diffie-hellman

I implemented [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) in Java with some large groups from [RFC 3526](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt). My output is a fairly large array of bytes. **Is it safe to use the first 448 bits (56 bytes) of the output for a blowfish key?** Should I transform the bytes in any way, or pick any specific bytes for the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a theoretical point of view, no, it is not safe. Not that I could pinpoint an actual attack; but the output of a Diffie-Hellman key exchange is an element of a group consisting in *q* elements and offering *sqrt(q)* security at most. Truncating parts of the encoding of that element does not look like a good idea...

The "proper" way is to use a one-way key derivation function. In simple words, process the Diffie-Hellman output with a good hash function such as [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and use the hash result as key. Hashing time will be negligible with regards to the Diffie-Hellman step. Java already includes fine implementations of SHA-256 and SHA-512, and if you are after compatibility with very old Java implementations (e.g. the Microsoft JVM which was coming with Internet Explorer 5.5) then you can use an independent Java implementation of SHA-2 such as the one in [sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/). Or possibly reimplement it from the spec (that's not hard): [FIPS 180-3 (a PDF file)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-3/fips180-3_final.pdf).

If you need more than 128 bits for your key then this means that you are a time-traveler from year 2050 or so; 128 bits are (much) more than enough to protect you for the time being, assuming that you use a proper symmetric encryption scheme.

Speaking of which: Blowfish is not really recommended anymore. It has 64-bit blocks, which implies trouble when the encrypted data length reaches a few gigabytes, a size which is not that big nowadays. You would be better off using a 128-bit block cipher such as the [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). Also, in any serious symmetric encryption system you will need a keyed integrity check. This can be done with a MAC (Message Authentication Code) such as [HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104), itself built over a hash function (then again, easy to implement, and there is a Java implementation in sphlib). Or, even better, use the AES in a combined encryption/MAC mode which will handle the tricky details for you (because using a block cipher properly is *not* easy); lookup [CWC](http://www.zork.org/cwc/) and [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (both are patent-free; the latter has been approved by NIST).

Comment: Very informative. I'm using the encryption for UDP traffic with fairly small packet sizes. From what I've read, Blowfish looked comparable to AES, but much faster. I've overlooked MACs before, but I'll take a closer look now.

Comment: For anything related to speed, you should measure. Blowfish was considered fast when compared to 3DES, about 12 years ago; but AES is much faster than 3DES. Blowfish is also known to have a slow key schedule (changing to a new key is expensive). From a security point of view, AES is much better, if only because it was scrutinized by many more cryptographers. The Blowfish designer even made a new version, called Twofish, which was a candidate for becoming the AES (but Rijndael was chosen instead, and became the AES).

Comment: The proper way is to use a standard, not to design cryptographic schemes yourself.

Comment: "Fast" is a double-edged sword: benefits users but also benefits brute-forcing.  Also one must consider optimized hw (asic/fpga) and sw implementations for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you propose depends on whether the most significant bits of a Diffie-Hellman exchange are hard core. There are some small results known that show that the most significant bits are unpredictable, but I'm not aware of a paper that is strong enough to show that your approach is correct.

However, there are several proposals for a key derivation from Diffie-Hellman keys.
E.g. a nice paper is NIST SP 800-135. So far this is only a draft and can be found [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsDrafts.html). However, it reviews some existing standards. Of course, using a standard is always preferable to develop it yourself.

While Thomas Pornin's proposal looks reasonable it is nonetheless an ad hoc solution. And to be on the safe side you should probably not use it. Rather I'd use something that has been analyzed (e.g. the key derivation scheme use in TLS version 1.2).